# Logstash custom drop filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

There is a possibility to match multiple values in filter if statement?

I have some values for which if at least one of them is not present in "message" field I need to drop the log line. Something like this:

```
if ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'] not in [message] { drop {} }
```

a.k.a if at least one of the values is present in message, then keep the log line, otherwise drop it.

There is a possibility to do something like that in logstash configuration?